# AEM 6.1 Projects - wrong groups

Tags: aem

When I create a new `Simple Project` in AEM 6.1 in the project view (`/projects.html`). I then add users to the projects groups (`editors`, `owners`, `observers`). But when I reload the page that shows the users and groups I can see all users are `observers`, no other groups are used, no matter what I configured.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply a bug in the UI. AFAIK it is fixed with 6.2.

Every project user is member of the `observers` group. If you put a user for example in the `editors` group, he will also be member of the `observers` group ad the UI is showing only one group per user and bad enough it's always the `observers` group that is shown, all the others are hidden.

Take a look at the `useradmin` and you will see that the users are in the correct groups.